# how to use css to center page title?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a hamburger menu that when clicked, it expands in both directions, I also have a page title that I would like to have centered on the page, but it doesn't want to work. The most luck I've had thus far is with adding a margin, but then the title moves when I click the hamburger menu.
I tried several options before resorting to asking, but they all seem to break the code or do nothing. Below are images and code corresponding to the current images.

```
#top {
            display:flex;
            background-color:black;
            width:100%;
            height: 200px;
            padding:5px;
        }
        #top #menu {
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
        #top h1{
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:row;
            color:red;
            justify-content:center;
        }
```

[image: Menu collapsed]

[image: Menu expanded]

Comment: you can you post html structure for the header/navigation?

Comment: Please put a full working example or at least your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try text-align: center; instead of justify-content: center;